# Eliminate zero from multiple columns which value is complete zero-oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to exclude the rows with zero values from all months showing in the below table.

This is sample data; there will be thousand of products with partial or full zero in between 12 months in real scenario. There will also be more months (columns) in real scenario.

[image]

The expected result will be look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case the affected columns are always natural numbers, you can sum them and check whether they are > 0.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE jan + feb + march + april > 0;
```

If they can be negative, but are always numbers, you can do the same based on their absolute values.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE ABS(jan) + ABS(feb) + ABS(march) + ABS(april) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In real scenario, you'll just have to put more columns into the `where` clause.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (prod_nm, jan, feb, mar, apr) as
  2    (select 'GRANULES' , 500, 200, 100, 500 from dual union all
  3     select 'INJECTION',   0,   0, 300, 550 from dual union all
  4     select 'VET-A'    ,   0,   0,   0, 300 from dual union all
  5     select 'VET-B'    ,   0,   0,   0,   0 from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where jan <> 0 or feb <> 0 or mar <> 0 or apr <> 0;

PROD_NM          JAN        FEB        MAR        APR
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
GRANULES         500        200        100        500
INJECTION          0          0        300        550
VET-A              0          0          0        300

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where + any:

```
with test (prod_nm, jan, feb, mar, apr) as
  (select 'GRANULES' , 500, 200, 100, 500 from dual union all
   select 'INJECTION',   0,   0, 300, 550 from dual union all
   select 'VET-A'    ,   0,   0,   0, 300 from dual union all
   select 'VET-B'    ,   0,   0,   0,   0 from dual
  )
select *
from test
where 0 < any (jan, feb, mar, apr);

PROD_NM          JAN        FEB        MAR        APR
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
GRANULES         500        200        100        500
INJECTION          0          0        300        550
VET-A              0          0          0        300

SQL>
```